# CSSStyleDeclaration differences in IE and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am looking into CSSStyleDeclaration in both IE 11 on W7 and latest Chrome. My markup is this:

```
<div style="padding:5px;min-height:70%">
```

The problem is that in Chrome it doesn't have min-height but IE shows it correctly. Can someone please explain why and if that's how it works what is a way of a reliable checking for height/width being specified in the style?

Thanks

Comment: @nietonfir if it's the last property being set, a semi-colon is not needed

Comment: @mark double check that you have not zoomed in on either browser, I can't tell you how many times that messed me up.

Comment: I am talking about this: element.style.cssText. In Chrome it doesn't have min-height, but in IE it does.

Comment: can you give some more html css of the parent nodes? if none of the parents have a reference-able height, then 70% will be 0.

Comment: I am using ngDialog for a popup. What I am showing is its template. That div is the most outer container.

Comment: `<html>` and `<body>` are the most outer containers of any html document. do those have any heights?

Comment: As I said, I am working in Angular environment. My templates do not have these tags, at least I am not specifying them.

Comment: if you right-click on the div and select 'inspect element' do you see html and body tags?

Comment: Just wonder why down voting?

Comment: wasn't me, someone else will have to explain

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="display:block;padding:5px;min-height:70%">
```